# swift slide out menu without sliding the navigationbar (programatically)

Tags: ios, menu, swift

I've been trying to make a left slide-out menu for a couple of days. I couldn't get any of the libraries to work with my application, so I resorted to raywenderlich's tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

However, it doesn't do exactly what I want. My main problem is that when I slide out the menu the navigation bar slides out with it. I need my navigation bar to stay where it is and only move the content underneath it.

I tried "self.view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationController.navigationBar)" But that didn't work.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

My current setup is made using a `ContainerViewController` that's set in my `appDelegate's`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()

    window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
```

This ContainerViewController is getting 2 childViewControllers.

the CenterViewControllerController (my content)

The CenterViewController will have the navigationController correctly set up.

```
var centerNavigationController: NavigationController!
var centerViewController: CenterViewController!
```

In the `ContainerViewController` `viewDidLoad`:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
    centerViewController.delegate = self

    // wrap the centerViewController in a navigation controller, so we can push views to it
    // and display bar button items in the navigation bar
    centerNavigationController = NavigationController(rootViewController: LandingPageVC())
    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

    centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
    centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
  }
```

and the SidePanelViewController (my menu & the problematic one.)

```
var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController?

  func addLeftPanelViewController() {
    if (leftViewController == nil) {
        leftViewController = SidePanelViewController()

        addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
    }
  }

  func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {
    println("addChildSidePanelController")

    view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, atIndex: 0)

    addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
    sidePanelController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
  }
```

The `SidePanelViewController` currently doesn't have a navigationController. I did try adding it. But that did not have the desired results.

Based on the comments, what I need to do is somehow making the ContainerViewController the one that has a navigationController, so both of it's childControllers should have that as well? However I have no clue how I would go about adding the navigationController on that level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I'm not using storyboards)

Libraries I tried:

ENSwiftSideMenu (did what I want. But spent 2 days trying to make it work with no results)

Brian Advent youtube tutorial

Dekatotoro's SlideMenuControllerSwift

wanaya/Slide-Menu

SWRevealViewController in Swift

Comment: You're correct in the assumption that it's the ContainerViewController that needs to be embedded in the navigation controller. You just need to instantiate a navigation controller in the app delegate with ContainerViewController as its rootViewController. Then make the nav controller the rootViewController of the window. The child controllers should not be embedded in their own navigation controllers (if I understand what you want, but that depends on what you want to happen when you select menu items in the MenuController).

Comment: BTW, what is this line supposed to be doing: `centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()`? UIStoryboard doesn't have that function, and anyway, I thought you weren't using a storyboard.

Comment: @rdelmar I will try to see if I can't do that. I think I know how I could go about it :), as for the storyBoard things. Ray's files had them. I haven't been able to figure out how to completely remove his storyboard without ruining stuff yet, but that's not my main problem right now. The functions are some he specified in an extension. But I don't use them. It's just that removing them as of right now, causes an error. I have several other issues atm. But this one is the only one that could potentially mean that I'd have to redo everything. So I need to fix this problem before the others.

Comment: @rdelmar I managed to implement the `navigationController` on the `ContainerViewController` level. However, I havn't been able to figure out how to make my `CenterViewController` the `LandingPage_VC()`. As you can see in the code, I used to do that with `rootViewController`. How would I go about making `LandingPage_VC()` as the `CenterViewController`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I really don't know what you're doing with the CenterViewController -- I don't know how you want it to relate to LandingPageVC. This seems overly complex to me. I also don't know if you really want CenterViewController embedded in its own navigation controller. What do you want to happen when the user selects a menu item?

Comment: @rdelmar I don't want the `CenterViewController` to be embedded in it's own `navigationController` anymore. now that the `ContainerViewController` is embedded in the `navigationController`. What I've been trying to do (still am unsuccesfully) is remove the `navigationController` for the `CenterViewController`. But make the `CenterViewController` my "Content". So I can easily change the CenterViewController, using a button from my Menu. (Or that was the plan anyway). I have no experience using ContainerViewControllers. If you have a better suggestion on how to meet my goal, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74465/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-mark-l).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with a custom container controller embedded in a navigation controller (to get the navigation bar). This controller would have two container views, a left one with a width of 80% of the screen width, and a right one that is full screen width; these can be set up in the storyboard. Swipe gesture recognizers added to the container controller's view would allow you to swipe the menu open and closed. The code below is all you would need in the container view controller to open and close the menu. The outlet, leftCon, is the constraint between the left edge of the left container view and its superview,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftCon: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftContainer: UIView!


    @IBAction func closeMenu(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        leftCon.constant = -leftContainer.frame.size.width
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3){
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func openMenu(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        leftCon.constant = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3){
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

I have an sample app (http://jmp.sh/5QwhYov) that demonstrates the setup of the controllers, but doesn't address how you would change the content in the main controller based on a selection in the menu controller. There are any number of ways that could be implemented, and I can address that if you can give me more details on how you want that to appear.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that I am not using storyboards. I've been trying to implement this programatically but without any success. The way I have it set up now, is with 2 different viewControllers, which has a lot of nice benefits. But of course if that's now possible, I'll have to look into containerviews inside a single viewController? I really appreciate the time you took making this answer, I'm sorry I failed to specify more precisely how I was working on it.

Comment: setup a constraint to the left side of your container programatically? use that as your leftCon

Comment: @milo526, I don't know why you would do it without a storyboard, that's certainly the easier way to go, but it can be done in code using the custom container controller api. If you're not familiar with that, you should read Apple's document, "Creating Custom Container View Controllers".

Comment: @rdelmar I don’t get it either, but since the OP reacted that he doesn’t use storyboards I wanted to mention that to you :)

Comment: There's a bunch of reasons why I prefer code to "wizywigs".  But that's not what the question is about. I found an article here explaining some of them. http://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code. Either way. I read the apple documentation on container views, and after having gotten a better understanding of them. I realized that this is actually how my menu is currently set up. I've only had a chance to try to add the navigationController on a higher level for a few hours now. I'll continue to try. But thought I'd leave an update and edit my original post

Comment: Based on the help you gave me in the chat. I did manage to get it working thanks to you. And I also got a direction to go in for how to change out the viewControllers afterwards.

I ended up reverting my `appDelegate` back to normal as the slide-out menu should only be available after login. I gave the embedded the `ContainerViewController` in the navigationStack like you told me to.  And to style the `navigationBar` after that, I had to do that in the `ContainerViewController`'s `viewDidload`. This answer should probably be edited though before it's accepted.

Comment: @Thomas, Sorry, there was an update to Jump Share, and that file ended up inside a folder, so the link changed. I've updated the link in the answer.

Comment: @rdelmar, you mention " but doesn't address how you would change the content in the main controller based on a selection in the menu controller. There are any number of ways that could be implemented" Can you please share the implementation...

Comment: @rdelmar I have a tabbar and when push from one view to another tabbar is hidden .. so how to show tabbar all the time ?