# Sidemenu with navigation bar that push content only

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate, hamburger-menu

I m having an issue implement side menu like this:

[image]

The point is the architecture.
I try to figure out which component will be the `AppDelegate`'s `Window`'s `rootViewController` (`UINavigationController`/`UIViewController`)
(And I know that `UINavigationController` is a `UIViewContoller`).

I thought over several options but none of them did my wanted job.

The main problems were:

1. The `NavigationBar` should be stay in place (no push to the side)
2. the Content (without the nav bar) should be push to the side together with the side menu

Any help will be more then welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using a setup like I talk about in my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425646/swift-slide-out-menu-without-sliding-the-navigationbar-programatically/29426304#29426304

Answer (score 0):

You have at root **UINavigationController**, which shows navigationBar at top.

NavController contains **UICollectionViewController**, which contains **UICollectionView** which contains two "full-screen" **UICollectionViewCells** side-by-side.

When you want to show sideMenu, you change collection layout (which most likely is **UICollectionViewFlowLayout** in this case).

This should keep you busy for a week, so you might check your customer, if this really is what they want to pay for or would they be happy with something bit different + additional features you could be doing in the same amount of time. If they want to pay, then there are loads of amazing things you can do with collection view!

Comment: Thanks @JOM! I figure this out finally. I added an `UIViewController` as rootVC. On top of it, I added 2 subviews: 1.`UINavigationController` 2.`UIViewController` of the side menu. Now, each time I want to toggle the side menu, I simply get to the `UINavigationController.topViewController.view` and animate it to push to the side. Accordingly, I move the side menu to enter the screen (from x=-200 to x = 200)